# How can I set up android's apksigner to run on windows?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to use apksigner with Android sdk version 29.0.3. When I run `apksigner verify <apk-name>.apk`, nothing happens. There is no output.

I took a look at the `apksigner.bat` and it seems like it's looking for a `find_java.bat` file and exiting early if it can't find it.

```
...
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
echo exist    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
if exist    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
if exist "%~dp0..\..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call "%~dp0..\..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
...
```

After looking through my sdk, it does not seem like that file exists. Is the apk signer just broken on windows? Or is there something I'm setting up incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You may have resolved this problem already, but for anyone else who encounters this problem:

You need to repair your environment using the SDK Manager. Simply open the SDK Manager and it should offer you to repair your SDK automatically.

As OP already correctly determined, the apksigner tool does not warn you when the find_java.exe is missing and a missing find_java.exe is a sign that your SDK is incomplete.

In my case, the whole tools directory was missing which was a loud and clear sign that my SDK was incomplete. And i still overlooked it.